# Spectral graph convolutional network, re-assigning indices

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convolution, spectral-analysis, graph-neural-network

This is a silly question for whom is familiar with the theory. I came across few papers that use a particular definition of convolution, designed to work with graphs, for example see section 2.1. of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.02907.pdf). I managed to find [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.367.6064&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that provides some background.

But as a recap if $G = (V,E)$ is a graph, with $V$ set of vertices and $E$ set of edges, such graph can be represented with an adjacency matrix $A_G$. The matrix $A_G$ can be diagonalized, because of its structure, say

$$
A_G = U_G \Lambda_G U_G^T
$$

is the decomposition in question. The graph convolution, associated to $G$ is defined as

$$
x *_{G}y=U_G g_\theta U_G^T x    \;\;\;\;\;\; (1)
$$

Suppose now specifically that $V(G) = \left\{1,\ldots, n \right\}$ (i.e. the set of labels is just a set of indices from $1$ to $n$). Here  $x$ is the function (feature vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$) defined on the graph.

Then assuming $g_\theta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is assigned the convolution results given by $(1)$. Suppose now I construct a graph $H$ by permuting the graph indices, hence I have to swap rows and columns of $A$ using permutation matrix $P$. Therefore

$$
A_H = PA_GP = P U_G \Lambda_G P U_G^T = U_H \Lambda_G U_H^T
$$

Accordingly I also need to apply $P$ to the feature vector $x_G$, to get the related $x_H$, hence the convolution on $H$ can be written as

$$
x_H *_H y = U_H g_\theta U_H^T x_H.
$$

In a nutshell this means the if I permute the indices the result of a convolution will be the same as the original up to a permutation of the indices.

Am I right?

This would also mean that If I have graph and I process the graph using a network already trained, and then I permute the indices and pass those to the very same network I should get exactly the same set of features up to a permutation.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: Graph convolutions are [equivariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_map) under permutations, i.e., permutation and convolution commute. That's desirable as the ordering of vertices is arbitrary, i.e., vertex ordering is not a graph [invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)).

Comment: It's actually still a bit unclear to me how this is implemented in practice. For a given trained DNN model can you pass any size graph? If you had a normal CNN the image size I don't think it would matter as the convolution there is a local operator. In a graph CNN, with spectral graph convolution, I think the question is a bit more involved as the size $\Lambda_G$ would depend on the graph size. The weights you would need to learn however are the ones of the polynomial $g_\theta$. But since the fourier transform is dependent on the graph size I'm not sure if this constrain to a specific size.

Comment: Depends how you parameterize $g_\theta$. You can pass in graphs of any size as long as $g_\theta$ is a function whose number of parameters is fixed, because $g_\theta(\lambda)$ can be evaluated for any $\lambda$ (however many). Moreover, if $g_\theta$ is a polynomial of order $K$ with weights $\theta_k$, $k \in [K]$, the convolution is provably localized in the $K$-neighborhood (i.e., the output doesn't depend on information more than $K$ hops away, as in traditional CNNs). In practice we don't compute the Fourier transform but evaluate $g_\theta(L)$ directly (by functional calculus).

Comment: so how does it work exactly? What's $L$? Also I assume to generalize you would need to train your model with graphs of different size right? I'm also a bit confused how backpropagation would work. For the localization in the $K$-neighborhood is there a proof somewhere I can look up?

Comment: $L$ is the [graph Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) (one def is $L = D - A$ where $A$ is the adjacency and $D$ the diagonal degree). Then $g_\theta(L) = U g_\theta(\Lambda) U^\top = U \sum_k \theta_k \Lambda^k U^\top = \sum_k \theta_k L^k$. (To not compute $L^k$ and leverage sparse operations, we compute $\bar{x}_k = L \bar{x}_{k-1}$, $\bar x_0 = x$.) As for any generalization, the model must have seen the distribution of graphs you want to generalize to. Localization proof is simply $(L^k)_{i,j} \neq 0$ iff there's a path shorter than $k$ between vertices $i$ and $j$.

Comment: For sake of my original question you answered anyway.